# Pagination PHP Changing Echo Text

Tags: php, pagination

I have recently installed a module to use with my Expression Engine backend to be able to locate stores.  The module uses Pagination to display multiple pages however when there is more then one page it simply links a ul > li tag with the number 1 and 2 and so on.  Is it possible to change this so that it displays Page 1 and Page 2 whilst keeping the same functionallity. I have found the pagination code below.

```
<?php if($numpages > 1): ?>
<ul id="store_locator_pagination">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=$numpages;$i++): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $i == $curpage ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="?page=<?php echo $i ?>&search=1&store_locator_radius=<?php echo $radius ?>&store_locator_location=<?php echo urlencode($location) ?>"><?php echo $i ?></a></li>
    <?php endfor ?>
</ul>
```

Any help would be appreciated.
Cheers,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<?php if($numpages > 1): ?>
<ul id="store_locator_pagination">
    <?php for($i=1;$i<=$numpages;$i++): ?>
        <li class="<?php echo $i == $curpage ? 'active' : '' ?>"><a href="?page=<?php echo $i ?>&search=1&store_locator_radius=<?php echo $radius ?>&store_locator_location=<?php echo urlencode($location) ?>"><?php echo'Page No-'. $i.'' ?></a></li>
    <?php endfor ?>
</ul>
```

should work for you

See this part

```
<?php echo'Page No-'. $i.'' ?>
```

just change `Page No-` text in qoutes to any text you require..

Answer (score 0):

The code

```
<?php echo $i ?>
```

In between your  tags can be easily modified to do what you want to do. Simply change that to add the word "Page" before it.

```
<?php echo "Page ".$i ?>
```